# How to resolve redirect 301 using Cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, cloudflare, worker

When trying to fetch URL-A in Cloudflare like

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})


async function handleRequest(request) {
  return fetch(request);
}
```

I'm getting the following response:

> 301 Moved Permanently location: URL-B

Can I resolve it in Cloudflare by making an additional fetch to URL-B instead of returning 301 response to the user?

Sounds possible, but didn't manage to find where I can get response's location attribute for URL-B.

How can I get the location of URL-B from URL-A's 301 response? (Already tried to console.log all knowns response attributes)

Comment: How did you get this message?

Comment: In Cloudflare workers there's the editor window which lets you put URL and test your logic. so when I'm adding the logic above and test it on the redirected resource I'm getting that response.

Comment: 301 Moved Permanently
age:1339
content-length:0
date:Thu, 20 Feb 2020 17:21:57 GMT
location:https://www.restOf URL-B
server:AmazonS3
via:1.1 26ffdea84ae47bd968b852d7f646629f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:SSsVIFGAm1PThxaJbt6FjYmyszjrO2jdblmFRVI3_cuvECrcTRqAWw==
x-amz-cf-pop:ORD52-C1
x-cache:Hit from cloudfront

Answer (score 1):

In the Worker, before sending the outbound request, you can specify that redirects should be followed.

Here's an example showing how to set that:

```
async function handleRequest(incomingRequest) {
    const outgoingRequest = new Request(
        incomingRequest.url,
        new Request(incomingRequest, {
            redirect: 'follow'
        })
    );

    return await fetch(outgoingRequest);
}
```